# What is the best practice to name the second instance of a class when the first instance is still in scope?

Tags: c#, naming-conventions

What is the best practice to name the second instance of a class? For example, for a class named Employee I create the first instance named as employee. What would be the best name for the second instance of the Employee class when the first instance is still in scope?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically the answer is that you *don't* create a second `Employee` variable. If you are dealing with two employees, use a collection like:

An array:

```
Employee[] employees = new Employee[2];
```

Or a List:

```
List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>();
```

If you aren't in a situation where you are just dealing with a group of employees than name the variable what it represents in the context of the code, like any other variable (`searchEmployee`, `newEmployee`, `employeeToBeFired`, etc.).

Comment: If it is method parameter which is better? ` bool Compare(Employee employee1, Employee employee2) ` or ` bool Compare(Employee firstEmployee, Employee secondEmployee) ` or ` bool Compare(Employee employee, Employee otherEmployee) `

Comment: In a method? Microsoft uses `objA` and `objB` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.referenceequals(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Name of your class looks like model because you are talking about `Employee`. When I am working with models I am giving names for new instances which represents current data structure in that scope.

Example, if I want to create new Employee I will name instance of `Employee` like: newEmployee. That object represents Employee which will be created.

In case that I have `EmployeeManager` (implements some functionalities) than I rather use name like `employeeManager` because I want to keep consistence with other code. Also it will be rarely case to create instances of same manager class in one scope.

I am recommending to you:

1. When dealing with models, use names for instances which describes purpose of your data in current scope. Example: `newEmployee`, `suspendedEmployee`, `valuableEmployee`.
2. When dealing with services, use names which describe service to keep consistent with code in your application. Example: `employeeRepositoryService`.

Answer (score 0):

I add the employee type or some word related with the function:

```
var employee = new Employee();
var employeeManager = new Employee(); //If is the manager
var employeeWithID = new Employee(); //If I use this to get the id
```

It's ok to add 1, 2, 3... or first, all depends of you.